# Connect two different apps using PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();

Tags: c#, windows-10, wifi-direct, win-universal-app, proximityapi

Working with Windows 10 Universal app.

Trying to utilise `Proximity API`. Using 2 Dell tablets with wifi connections.  There is a couple of good examples demonstrating data transfer using `Wifi Direct + Proximity API` and devices running **the same app**. My problem is that I have the two different apps (with different Package Family Names). I've tried using `PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities.Add()` method without success. My code looks like this:

```
public async Task FindPeersAsync()
{
    PeerInformationList = null;

    if ((PeerFinder.SupportedDiscoveryTypes & PeerDiscoveryTypes.Browse) == PeerDiscoveryTypes.Browse)
    {
        if (PeerFinder.AllowWiFiDirect)
        {
            PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities.Add("Server", "app1PackageFamilyName!App");
            PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities.Add("Client", "app2PackageFamilyName!App");}");

            PeerInformationList = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();

            DisplayStatusMessage(PeerInformationList == null
                 ? "Found no peer"
                 : $"I found {PeerInformationList.Count()} devices(s) executing this same app!");
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayStatusMessage("WIFI direct not available");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayStatusMessage("Browse not available");
    }
}
```

My `PeerFinder.Role` is set to `PeerRole.Peer`(by default).

Example code is taken from here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.peerfinder.alternateidentities.aspx

Edit: If I use the same app on both tablets I can see the other device but this is not possible if I'm running different apps on the 2 devices.

My question is - is using Wifi Direct filetransfer possible between different apps (both of them windows 10 universal) and if yes what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the docs, each app must be have an alternate identity of the other; so both have two identities. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes @x0n each app has its own identity `app1PackageFamilyName!App` and `app2PackageFamilyName!App` in my sample code.

Comment: Not quite sure about `client` and `server` - according to the docs it should be windows and windows phone if targeting different platforms but what about universal app with windows 10 now?